# How Do I Add Dropdown Menus (Select Menus) to Modals and Extract Information from Them in Discord.js V14?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I Was Wondering How To Add Select Menus to Modals in Discord.js V14, Can Somebody Explain How To Do It and/or Link Me A guide For it?

i tried Searching up a guide on how to do it and did not find any results, please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an offical [Discord.JS Guide Page](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#building-and-sending-select-menus) about using Select Menus.

Comment: Broken link, updated one: https://discordjs.guide/message-components/select-menus.html#select-menus

Also, to directly answer OP's question, only text inputs are currently supported in modals, not select menus nor buttons (2 default buttons show up in order to submit or cancel your query, but that's it).